# Tap issue with Ionic and Cordova on iOS 10

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic2, ios10

**iOS 10** it's still in beta, but it will be released on Tuesday the 13th.

I install the beta on my iPad and I notice that the tap is not working very well. (single tap not working, you have to tap several times to simulate a single tap (or click a button, change page and so on)

I am currently running ios 10.0.1 (updated last night) and i'm still facing this issue.

Is anybody facing the same problem?

I can see this behaviour only on my app, other apps are working fine.

The setup is:

**ionic 1.3.1**

**cordova 6.3.1**

Is there anything changed on **iOS 10** events that I need to bare in mind? sorry for the vague question, but it's something I need to fix before they release it officially or I will have a lot of angry customers.

Thank you !!!

---

**SMALL UPDATE**

Replacing `ng-click` with `on-tap` should solve part of this issue. You will still have problems with `ui-sref` and with any other place that doesn't use `ng-click` tho.

I've posted this issue in a bunch of different places, if you wanna keep track of it, they are here:

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/6928#issuecomment-253463917

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-tap-issues-with-ios10/66764

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick?

Comment: Yes, I tried with fastclick but nothing seam to change at all...

Comment: Yeah, I forgot ionic already has a 300ms delay removal built in (my bad). It's forked hammer.js? Check that you're not using ngClick (and remove fast click if you haven't already). Make sure you read ionic 's tap & click document in detail in case it helps to point you in the right direction.

Comment: I am using ngClick...can you explain why I shouldn't?

Comment: Not really. I can only parrot what I've read in the tap & click document, which explains that ngClick conflicts with ionic 's mechanics sometimes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIXED!**

I finally fixed this. I don't know if this will be useful for you tho. The issue was one plugin I bought from ionic market, and to be precise it was this one:

https://market.ionic.io/plugins/ion-time-picker

I already sent an email to the developer, but if you are using this plugin, it may be the cause of ios10 not working.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for bringing the issue to my attention, it has been fixed and new version released, make sure to download it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use (tap) directive instead of (click) directive.

Angular 2:

Ionic provides you with hammerjs under the hood, if you use the (tap) directive angular 2 will do all the wiring to connect that directive with hammerjs and that removes the 300ms delay. 
Good luck.

Example:

```
<my-component (tap)="doSomething()"></my-component>
```

Angular 1.x:

Try with http://ryanmullins.github.io/angular-hammer/
Is the recommended repository from the guys of hammerjs for Angular 1.x

Example:

```
<div hm-tap="doSomething"></div>
```

Comment: I'm using angular 1, but I'll give it a try

Comment: I have edited the response to cover angular 1.x too, good luck!

Comment: The issue was that I was using fast-click as a component, just switched it with angular-hammer and issue seems to be solved, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i found one solution on website. but i don't use ng-material in my app. 
did you try this????

```
.config(function( $mdGestureProvider ) {
          $mdGestureProvider.skipClickHijack();
  })
```

Comment: Im not usong it neither, and anyway there's an ionic alternative for this and that's about the 300ms. That's not the issue we are having

Comment: hi nick, i tried many things. i referenced https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/page/tap/    <- this page. and each div added data-tap-disabled="true" . and it worked well. did u find other solutions??

Comment: Hi, no, still looking into this.
You said that it worked, so what did you do exactly? did you add data-tap-disabled="true" everywhere?

Comment: i just added 'data-tap-disabled="true" to html tag. however, 
ion scroll doesn't work. 

i think that find out other solution is better.